# Getting user id and assigning it to a project table row 2x tables

Tags: php, pdo

Can someone shed light onto what these error/s mean?
I'm learning through trial and error but stumped on how to go about getting the ID from ***table1(students)*** and then inserting that id into ***table 2(projects)*** along with other values.

I learn by doing but this is my first time trying to get data cross tables and insert into one from another. Any help or hints greatly appreciated.

```
$project = "INSERT INTO projects(id, project_title, project_description, project_text)
            VALUES(:id, :project_title, :project_description,:project_text)
            SELECT id FROM students WHERE students.id=:id
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=:id";
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT id FROM students WHERE students.id=? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ' at line 3 in /Applications/AMPPS/www/standout/start-project/step1.php:12 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/AMPPS/www/standout/start-project/step1.php(12): PDO->prepare('INSERT INTO pro...') #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/AMPPS/www/standout/start-project/step1.php on line 12

Comment: Why do you need an access to table `student` if you just select `id` from that table filtered by id? What about the query: you should add a DBMS tag, but for DBMSes that I know `insert ... values` and `insert ... select..` are not compatible, you should use only one of this. Preferrably `insert ... select ...` to ensure you will not get null in `id` column for non-existing `id`

Comment: Thx for comment, so the SELECT id from student table would be wrong? Basically want to have it so when a student creates a project that the project they make is assigned to them only and not any other student. I thought that would need to select the id from students to then add that id to the projects table so the students id is assigned to that project? Would that be the wrong way to go about it?

Comment: Don't worry figured it out